# wpf filter xml data on a listview

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview

I want to save patient data on a xml file like the one above,

```
<Patients>
  <Patient name="Joao" bi="12345678" age="21" allergies="Pollen" address="" cellphone="961556408" medication="" sex="Male" />
</Patients>
```

And I want to show the patients on a ListView but I wanted to make a feature which the user could filter patients by name, date of birth , cellphone or BI but I don't know how to do it since the data is on a XML file.

what I Have so far:
XAML:

```
<DockPanel Margin="2.4,7.2,8,1.4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,541.2,10" Name="txtFilter" TextChanged="txtFilter_TextChanged" />
            <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="50,-27,541.2,10" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="SearchCombo" SelectedValuePath="Content" Margin="380,-45,279.2,10"  Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Height="21">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Name"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="date of birth"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Cellphone"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="BI"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <ListView Name="lvPatients" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PatientsData}, XPath=Patient}" SelectionChanged="lvPatients_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath =@name}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="BI" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath = @bi}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Cellphone" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath = @cellphone}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Sex type" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath = @sex}"/>

                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
```

C# code :
Combobox code:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvPatients.ItemsSource);
    switch (SearchCombo.SelectedValue.ToString())
    {
        case "Name": 
            datePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //Shows the date picker
            txtFilter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Hides the text box
            view.Filter = PatientNameFilter;
            break;
        case "Date of birth": 
            datePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Shows the date picker
            txtFilter.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // Hides the text box
            view.Filter = PatientDateFilter;
            break;
        case "BI": 
            datePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //Shows the date picker
            txtFilter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Hides the text box 
            view.Filter = PatientBIFilter;
            break;
        case "Cellphone": 
            datePicker.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //Shows the date picker
            txtFilter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Hides the text box 
            view.Filter = PatientPhoneFilter; // Cellphone
            break;

    }
}
```

So the problem is I have no idea how to filter the data on the listView. For example if I Write "Joao" on the texbox the listView should only show the patient "Joao" and everything that has to do with him/her ( name,date of birth,sex,etc..).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `CollectionViewSource` that is bound to the `ListView`. This will allow for dynamic filtering.

Here's a blog post explaining how to do so:

https://grantwinney.com/using-a-textbox-and-collectionviewsource-to-filter-a-listview-in-wpf/

Docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, using straight XML you may have a few problems converting the attribute values to their native types. See:

[How do I use CollectionViewSource to sort xml records by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041620/how-do-i-use-collectionviewsource-to-sort-xml-records-by-date)

Also,

[Filter XML data from XmlDataProvider using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527392/filter-xml-data-from-xmldataprovider-using-xpath)